# Python class objects appending to list

Tags: python

I have a list of class objects that I would like to distribute to other lists as objects and then these lists should be called to provide interaction with the objects within.

The issue that I cannot overcome at the moment is when trying to append the objects with a for loop from the first list to the second one and instead getting the new list populated with the class objects I get their pointers to the memory.

This is currently running on Python 3.x if any difference.

I have seen some cases where the suggestion is to play with  `__str__`   and
`__repr__` but I don't come to a solution for my case.

```
class Robot():
    """Test class"""
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

r = Robot(10)
r1 = Robot(15)

mylist1 = [r, r1]
mylist2=[]

for item in mylist1:
    mylist2.append(item)
print(mylist2)
```

I would expect to get something like `[r, r1]`

This is the result I get instead:

```
[<__main__.Robot object at 0x000001285CEE33C8>, <__main__.Robot object at 0x000001285CEE3748>]
```

Comment: Well, the problem is the missing `__str__` or `__repr__` method; without is, that's just how Python represents those instances. Apart from that, your code works correctly.

Comment: There isn't really a way to do this. Think about it like this: What if you initialized `myList1` like `myList1 = [Robot(10), Robot(15)]`. What should it print? The variable names aren't a part of the object. They're a separate label associated with the object. The objects don't know what variables names they've been given.

Comment: Those two items are exactly `r` and `r1`: just their string representation (which defaults to this, since you haven't defined a string representation yourself for the class).

Comment: There's nothing wrong here: you are appending instances of `Robot`, which are indeed located elsewhere in memory, and you only have pointers to them. This is how Python works. If you would like the string representation of these objects to be different, read about `__repr__`.

Comment: What are `r` and `r1`? They are just reference names that can change all the time the object they point to. What's printed is exactly what's expected - the pointers/references of the two objects you created.

Comment: `r` and `r1` are variable names. They are not the robots themselves. They are just labels, post-it nodes stuck on the robots, and you can add as many of those post-it notes as you want. But you are adding the robots themselves to the list, not those names. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for more information on how Python names work. If you want your robots to be shown in a list with a name, you need to explicitly give the robots names (as a attribute of the robot itself), and use `__repr__` to create a string to be shown when printing a list, where you include the names.

Comment: You might though want to name your robots, such that `__init__` will also get an id as a parameter. Then, you can implement `__str__` to return that ID and then printing your list should call it and print the ids

Comment: (And you really want to use `print(r)` and `print(r1)` and `print(mylist1)` too, because you'll find that the output will look very familiar, it is not `mylist2` that is special here).

Comment: If you want `["r", "r1"]`, you _could_ try something like `[next(v for v in globals() if globals()[v] is obj) for obj in mylist1]`, but your really, _really_ shoudn't.

Comment: @tobias_k: please, no showing off how well we know Python internals here. This user is at the beginning of their journey to learn programming, we really don't need to show off too-clever-by-half tricks here. You are now confusing matters, muddying the waters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are we sure about that? OP seems to understand that those are the memory addresses, and that _usually_ one should use `__str__` or `__repr__`, but that those don't work here. If OP (for whatever reason) really _needs_ the result as `[r, r1]`, and not e.g. `[Robot(10), Robot(15)]`, then this might help. But as I noted, it's usually not a good thing to consider.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down-voted. Everybody is struggling to answer - it means that it is not a trivial "read the docs" one. It should be up-voted. I do agree that the request is quite odd, but still...

Comment: @tobias_k: they did their research and read that they are seeing memory addresses. What they need is information how Python names work, and why expecting to see `r` and `r1` is not the way this works. If I could duplicate this to Ned Batchelder's excellent article I linked to before, I would. They don't literally want to find the names these objects were assigned to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by others in comments.In your code at the moment you are getting the expected result as `r` and `r1` are the instances of the class. In case you want to differentiate your instances on the basis of name and want to return the same you can pass `name` argument and define `__repr__` to represent your output when `str(instance)` is being called. Just giving you a heads up:

```
class Robot():
    """Test class"""
    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

r = Robot(10,'r')
r1 = Robot(15,'r1')

mylist1 = [r, r1]
mylist2 = []

for item in mylist1:
    mylist2.append(item)
print(mylist2)
```

Result:

```
[r, r1]
```

Otherway could be to use a dictionary for mapping

```
class Robot():
    """Test class"""
    def __init__(self, age,name):
        self.age = age
        self.name=name

r = Robot(10,'r')
r1 = Robot(15,'r1')

mylist1 = [r, r1]
d={}

for item in mylist1:
    d[item.name]=item
print(d)
```

Output

```
{'r': <__main__.Robot instance at 0x0000000010BAD708>, 'r1': <__main__.Robot instance at 0x0000000010BAD148>}
```

Comment: Right, now do add a bit more explanation to this. Don't just give code. Explain why this works, why theirs doesn't.

Comment: [This article](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/__str__-vs-__repr) will make everything clear